# Logback file appender doesn't flush immediately

Tags: java, logging, io, logback, flush

For some circumstances I need to force flushing in logback's file appender immediately. I've found in [docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/encoders.html#PatternLayoutEncoder) this option is enabled by default. Mysteriously this doesn't work. As I see in the sources underlying process involves `BufferedOutputSream` correctly. Is there any issues with `BufferedOutputSream.flush()` ? Probably this is rather related to the flushing issue.

**Update**:
I found the issue on Windows XP Pro SP 3 and on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga).
I used these libs:

```
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
logback-classic-1.0.6.jar
logback-core-1.0.6.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
```

The `logback.xml` is:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/somepath/file.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>file.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**Updated:**
I'd provide a unit test but that seems not so simple.
Let me describe the issue more clearly.

1. Event of logging occurred
2. Event is passed into file appender
3. Event is serialized with defined pattern
4. Serialized message of event is passed to the file appender and is
   about to write out to output stream
5. Writing to the stream is finished, output stream is flushed (I've
   checked the implementation). Note that `immidiateFlush` is true by
   default so method `flush()` is invoked explicitly
6. No result in the file!

A bit later when some underlying buffer was flowed the event appears in the file.
So the question is: does output stream guarantee immediate flush?

To be honest I've already solve this by implementing my own `ImmediateRollingFileAppender` that leverages facility of `FileDescriptor` of immediate syncing. Anybody interested in can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072895/538514).

So this is not a logback issue.

Comment: On which operating system have you discovered this ?

Comment: Post your logback configuration.

Comment: Can you please define "Mysteriously this doesn't work"? Providing a unit test would be very useful. BTW, which version of the JDK are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I decided to bring my solution to everybody.
Let me clarify first of all that this is not a logback issue and not a JRE problem. This is described in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29) and generally shouldn't be an issue until you are faced with some old school integration solutions over the file syncing.

So this is a logback appender implemented to flush immediately:

```
public class ImmediateFileAppender<E> extends RollingFileAppender<E> {

    @Override
    public void openFile(String file_name) throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            File file = new File(file_name);
            if (FileUtil.isParentDirectoryCreationRequired(file)) {
                boolean result = FileUtil.createMissingParentDirectories(file);
                if (!result) {
                    addError("Failed to create parent directories for [" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "]");
                }
            }

            ImmediateResilientFileOutputStream resilientFos = new ImmediateResilientFileOutputStream(file, append);
            resilientFos.setContext(context);
            setOutputStream(resilientFos);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeOut(E event) throws IOException {
        super.writeOut(event);
    }

}
```

This is corresponding output stream utility class. Because of some methods and fields of original `ResilientOutputStreamBase` that was supposed for extending initially have packaged access modifiers I had to extend `OutputStream` instead and just copy the rest and unchanged of `ResilientOutputStreamBase` and `ResilientFileOutputStream` to this new one. I just display the changed code:

```
public class ImmediateResilientFileOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    // merged code from ResilientOutputStreamBase and ResilientFileOutputStream

    protected FileOutputStream os;

    public FileOutputStream openNewOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return new FileOutputStream(file, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.flush();
                os.getFD().sync(); // this's make sence
                postSuccessfulWrite();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                postIOFailure(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And finally the config:

```
<appender name="FOR_INTEGRATION" class="package.ImmediateFileAppender">
    <file>/somepath/for_integration.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>for_integration.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</pattern>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: JFYI, the bug was reported in Logback => https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-735

Answer (score 1):

You have done a good job - well done. Here is a proposal to get it more concise:

```
public class ImmediateFlushPatternLayoutEncoder extends PatternLayoutEncoder {
    public void doEncode(ILoggingEvent event) throws IOException {
        super.doEncode(event);
        if (isImmediateFlush()) {
             if (outputStream.os instanceof FileOutputStream) {
                 ((FileOutputStream) outputStream.os).getFD().sync();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

In configuration, you have to use that specific encoder:

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ImmediateFlushPatternLayoutEncoder">
```

Not tested. Probably there will be visibility issues with fields, **requiring to use logback `ch.qos.logback.core.recovery` package itself**.

By the way, I invite you to [submit a bug report](http://logback.qos.ch/bugreport.html) to logback to get an additional option `immediateSync` on `LayoutWrappingEncoder`.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. Will do this one of these days. Thanks for maintaining us and the project.

Comment: this outputStream is a ResilientFileOutputStream,and it's not extended from FileOutputStream,so it does not has the getFD() method.

Comment: Right. I updated my answer... but I have not tested more than before

Comment: Ah crud.  Looks like this would need reflection to pull the protected os field from ResilientOutputStreamBase.

Answer (score -1):

Many monitoring middleware find the new events by check for updates of time stamp and file size. For this reason, it need to time the event is recorded, time stamp and file size is updated.

This class could solve it

```
public class MyFileAppender<E> extends FileAppender<E> {
    protected void writeOut(E event) throws IOException {
        super.writeOut(event);
        ResilientFileOutputStream resilientFos = (ResilientFileOutputStream) super.getOutputStream();
        resilientFos.flush();
        resilientFos.getChannel().force(true);
    }
}
```

Set MyFileAppender class for appender.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="MyFileAppender">
```

I hope that is logback solves this problem.

Comment: I am facing problem with this solution, for interrupted threads "resilientFos.getChannel().force(true)" closes the file channel and the logging stops thereafter.