# I am trying to log text from the console to a text file, and the text file isn't being created

Tags: java, logging, java.util.scanner, java.util.logging

Here is my code, I am wondering why it isn't logging anything. When I type into the console it says:

Hello

Apr 08, 2013 10:13:47 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log

INFO: Hello

However, nothing is being logged to any files.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        while (1 == 1) {
            String text;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            text = in.nextLine();
            FileHandler fileTxt;
            SimpleFormatter formatterTxt;
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
            logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
            fileTxt = new FileHandler("../loggedText.txt");
            formatterTxt = new SimpleFormatter();
            fileTxt.setFormatter(formatterTxt);
            logger.addHandler(fileTxt);
            logger.info(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not wanting to be one of "those" people, but have you considered using a dedicated logging library like log4j instead of the built-in logging classes?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop never terminates which means the JVM never performs a proper shutdown.  The FileHandler is only closed and synched if all the logging shutdown hook executes normally.  It is possible that the data was written but is never [synched with the filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072878/i-o-concept-flush-vs-sync).

Let's create a corrected example that can terminate normally:

```
public class main {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(""); //Prevent G.C.

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        FileHandler fileTxt = new FileHandler("../loggedText.txt");
        fileTxt.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        logger.addHandler(fileTxt);

        System.out.println("root.level " + logger.getLevel());
        System.out.println("FileHandler.level " + fileTxt.getLevel());
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter text: ");
            text = in.nextLine();
            if (text != null && !text.isEmpty() 
                    && !"quit".equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
                logger.info(text);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Done!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will output the following to the console:

```
root.level INFO
FileHandler.level ALL
Enter text: hello
Nov 22, 2016 10:39:19 AM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
INFO: hello
Enter text: quit
Done!
```

On the filesystem is `loggedText.txt` containing:

```
Nov 22, 2016 10:39:19 AM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
INFO: hello
```

If you can't terminate normally you need to explicitly call `FileHandler.close()` on the handlers you create.

Note: The logged class name and method name are incorrect which is known as [JDK-8152389](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152389).