# Basics of Serialization in java not understood

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, serialization, serializable

I am not able to understand the basics of `Serialization` in Java 1.6.

Below is the `Dog` Class containing an instance variable of `Collar` Class:

**Dog.java**

```
public class Dog implements Serializable {

private Collar collar;

public Collar getCollar() {
    return collar;
}

public void setCollar(Collar collar) {
    this.collar = collar;
}

}
```

The Collar class does not implements `Serializable` interface as shown below:

**Collar.java**

```
public class Collar {

private int size;

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}

}
```

Now when I try to serialize the `Dog` then why it does not throw an `NotSerializableException` ? According to the contract the entire object graph should  implement `Serializable` but my `Collar` class does not fulfill that.

Below is the main method for this demo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("E:\\test.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        // No exception thrown here, WHY?
        // test.ser file is getting created properly.
        os.writeObject(dog);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\test.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Dog dog1 = (Dog)ois.readObject();
        // Here I am getting a null Collar object
        Collar c1 = dog1.getCollar();
```

Kindly explain this, I am totally confused while trying to implement all the theoretical stuffs :(

Comment: Please add these lines `outputStream.flush();` `outputStream.close();` before you read from the file and then report back your findings

Comment: You said it yourself: the entire *object graph* must be serializable, not all the classes your code happens to mention.

Comment: @Multithreader NO difference found if I add the two lines mentioned above

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can you please elaborate your answer? It sounds interesting

Comment: Well, your entire object graph is just the `Dog` object itself. It holds no references to any other objects. If you used `setCollar` with a non-null argument, then you'd extend the object graph to encompass that object as well, and get the exception you expect.

Comment: @WhoAmI When you write to an `OutputStream` you need to `.close()` it (which does a `.flush()` and potentially more - no need to do both) to ensure that any buffered data is actually written. Without you might never write the last few bytes and therefore read corrupt data. For file output you might also want to sync: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072878/i-o-concept-flush-vs-sync

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ok, it means what I understood by the term `ObjectGraph` is totally incorrect. I read all sorts of bookish language and it ha confused me totally :( Can you please elaborate on the term `ObjectGraph` and post it in answer section so that I can close this thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you had a misunderstanding of the concept of *object graph*. In this graph, the nodes are *instances* (*not* classes) and the edges are formed from values of reference-typed instance variables.

Applied to your example,

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
```

creates an object graph consisting of a single node, the `Dog` instance. The `collar` variable is `null` so its value doesn't form an edge no another node. But, if you add a line such as

```
dog.setCollar(new Collar());
```

now your object graph contains two nodes, connected by the edge formed by the value in the `collar` instance variable.

Now, all this applied to serialization means that your posted example is serializing the one-node object graph, whose all nodes are serializable, but if you added a collar, that graph would contain a non-serializalbe node and you would get the exception you expect.

Answer (score 9):

Could be because your `dog` doesn't have a `collar`!

Try with

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setCollar(new Collar());
```

Comment: Interesting.  So serialization is about instantiated classes, not their declarations.  In retrospect, this makes sense since we could replace Collar with Accessory, and have Collar and FoodBowl being implementers of Accessory.  Accessory isn't worth jack for serialization - we need the actual concrete classes.