# Java I/O - java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException thrown while trying to open file that were written

Tags: java, linux, io

I have encountered with I/O issue in my java program. My program uses java 7 with Tomcat 7 under Linux. Thread 1 creates an object and serialize it to file with JAXB:

```
public static void export1(JAXBContext context, Object object, Path filePath){
    try {
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(object, filePath.toFile());
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Then a notification is sent to external entities. Threads that handles incoming requests encounter with:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: PATH_TO_FILE
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
```

I have read some posts about [I/O concept flush vs sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072878/i-o-concept-flush-vs-sync) but I am still confused. Will refactor my code to the next code that uses unbuffered output stream solve my issue?

```
public static void export2(JAXBContext context, Object object, Path filePath){
    try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(filePath)) {
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(object, os);
    } catch (JAXBException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Or should I use File descriptor directly to synchronize OS buffers with underlying device?

```
public static void export3(JAXBContext context, Object object, Path filePath) {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath.toFile())) {
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(object, fos);
        fos.getFD().sync();
    } catch (JAXBException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any? Your second example should work without a problem

Comment: The problem occured under heavy load on my system. Didn't manage to reproduce it for now with the new code.