# Android - Power off after files are copied results in corrupted files

Tags: java, android, filesystems, android-file

I'm using this code

```
for (Uri fileUri : files) {
  File destFile = ...
  InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);

  FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, destFile);
}
```

And if user remove the battery of the phone after this `for` cycle then the some files (lasts) are corrupted.

Is it possible to prevent this?

I tried copy the InputStream to the temp directory and then use

```
 FileUtils.moveFile(temp, destFile);
```

for each file but there was the same problem.

Can I somehow close the copied files? Make sure they are copied successfully?

Comment: Is `FileUtils` a class you wrote? In method `copyInputStreamToFile()`, are `flush` and `sync` used?  As an example, see method `copyToFile()` at line 190 of [this file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/core/java/android/os/FileUtils.java).

Comment: No. FileUtils are from Apache Commons IO. Thanks for your info. I will try the copyToFile() that you suggested.

Comment: Some more info is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072878/i-o-concept-flush-vs-sync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by using this:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

[...]

out.flush();
out.getFD().sync();
```

from [I/O concept flush vs sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072878/i-o-concept-flush-vs-sync)

Look at the https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/core/java/android/os/FileUtils.java and method `copyToFile(InputStream inputStream, File destFile)` It's nice example how to sole this.

Thanks to qbix!