# Are FileChannel.force and FileDescriptor.sync both needed?

Tags: java, io, storage, nio

In  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730521/really-force-file-sync-flush-in-java, the author writes in the summary of the answers:

> Use c.force(true) followed by s.getFD().sync() for Java NIO

My question is: do you really need both? Isn't force enough? Aren't force and sync just different interfaces for doing the same thing? I can't find anyplace where this is confirmed.

Comment: Currently, both implementations call the native function `fsync()` (or `fdatasync()` in case of FileChannel.force with false). I've found them in src/java.base/unix/native/libnio/ch/UnixFileDispatcherImpl.c (FileChannel native end call) and src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/FileDescriptor_md.c (FileDescriptor native implementation) - OpenJDK's commit id ee57e731d03

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My understanding is that the correct answer is No.

[FileChannel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html).force calls [fdatasync](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fdatasync.html) or [fsync](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fsync.html). This can be seen in jdk/src/solaris/native/sun/nio/ch/FileChannelImpl.c on of the OpenJDK source code.
[FileDescriptor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) calls fsync (To find this out was more complex. I finally traced it to jvm.cpp).

I am the "author" of the linked question. So I was wrong. What is NOT enough is [FileOutputStream.flush.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29) because it is a no-op. You therefore either need force or sync.