# Using FileChannel to fsync a directory with NIO.2

Tags: java, nio, java-7

I just discovered that with NIO.2, at least under Linux, I can open a `FileChannel` on a directory, and calling [force(true)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#force%28boolean%29) calls `fsync()` on the underlying file descriptor. Without getting into whether this [*should* be necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433057/is-rename-without-fsync-safe), it's nice to finally have this functionality available in pure Java.

I haven't been able to find anywhere that this behaviour is documented, though. Can I count on this working on all Unix platforms, in future versions of Java, and in non-Oracle JVMs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650327/are-filechannel-force-and-filedescriptor-sync-both-needed

Comment: That's about files; only Java 7 seems to allow `fsync` on directories, and I'd like to know if this is on purpose.

Comment: Ah gotcha, yea see @EJP's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following thread: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2015-May/003140.html

It was not technically supported, but looks like support will be retained as many applications rely on it.

Answer (score -1):

You can count on whatever the documentation says, and on nothing else.

Comment: Unlike `FileInputStream`, the documentation for `FileChannel.open()` doesn’t say that it only works on regular files, which I guess will have to do.